Networking Errors on KVM
I am trying to run a KVM virtual machine on Debian 11 (Bullseye)

I'm also running this from crouton on ChromeOS in case that's like really crucial, but I don't think it is.

Here's the error:
Unable to complete install: 'Requested operation is not valid: network 'default' is not active'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 65, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/createvm.py", line 2001, in _do_async_install
    installer.start_install(guest, meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/install/installer.py", line 701, in start_install
    domain = self._create_guest(
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/install/installer.py", line 649, in _create_guest
    domain = self.conn.createXML(install_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 4366, in createXML
    raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateXML() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: Requested operation is not valid: network 'default' is not active

I tried the following guide: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036297/cant-start-kvm-guest-network-default-is-not-active
but the fix provided "sudo virsh net-start default" fails:
sudo virsh net-start default
[sudo] password for luhgarlicbread: 
error: Failed to start network default
error: internal error: Failed to apply firewall rules /usr/sbin/iptables -w --table filter --list-rules: # Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): Could not fetch rule set generation id: Invalid argument


Additionally:
On KVM > Edit (at the top) > Connection Details
Pressing the "Start Network" button on the bottom left also errors out:

Error starting network 'default': internal error: Failed to apply firewall rules /usr/sbin/iptables -w --table filter --list-rules: # Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): Could not fetch rule set generation id: Invalid argument



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 65, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 101, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 57, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/network.py", line 69, in start
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 3436, in create
    raise libvirtError('virNetworkCreate() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: Failed to apply firewall rules /usr/sbin/iptables -w --table filter --list-rules: # Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): Could not fetch rule set generation id: Invalid argument

Any way to bypass all network checks / disable networking on KVM entirely? Any tips, tricks, or fixes I could try?
This seems like a lotta issues.
PS: I have gotten through all of my other issues. One prominent one being that libvirtd won't start with (I think it is) systemctl so I just start the process manually from terminal and keep that term. window open while I try to make my vm in KVM using virt-manager.

The error message is each time about iptables-nft vs iptables-legacy. So is one of these commands working (as root)? two? none?: iptables-nft-save , iptables-legacy-save?

A solution that I've set my self is to scrap built-in networking and interfaces in KVM and instead use openvswitch as virtual adapter, then you need to create your own firewall rules to perform NAT, this way you're in full control over networking.

The first (nft) command errors out:
:sudo iptables-nft-save
iptables-nft-save v1.8.7 (nf_tables): Could not fetch rule set generation id: Invalid argument"
The second command (legacy) runs and outputs a bunch. Too much for the character limits on a comment.

How could I go about this route? Any guides, tutorials, or simple commands?

@JohnGarlic See linked tutorial for openvswitch in virt-manager, this is however only half of the job, next half is NAT for which you'd need to learn a bit about NAT in nftables to enable networking for this scenario (not easy) https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/libvirt-open-vswitch
